# Enumerating events of a class at runtime

Tags: c#, events

I have an abstract class `Capability` which models each capability of a physical device. I then have subclasses such as `InputSwitch` and `TemperatureSensor` which can each fire different events.

`InputSwitch` is fairly straightforward - when the physical switch is pressed, the object representing it raises the event `Triggered`.

`TemperatureSensor` is slightly more complicated in that it has two events - `TemperatureOK` and `TemperatureAlarm`.

There are more than just these two subclasses, each with differing events they can raise. There may also be more instances of any of the subclasses added during runtime.

The end user needs to be able to specify what (if anything) happens when these events are triggered and so essentially I'm looking at allowing the user to browse the possible events across all of the `Capability` instances. Each capability is currently stored in a `List<Capability>`.

Is there a way to enumerate the available events?

Comment: I don't think that using reflection to get a list of all events is a viable approach. What if you add events that should not be selectable? Use a manually defined list of events.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want exactly, do you want to enumerate the events of your class ? or just raised events of an instance of a class ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I see what you mean, but these classes are specifically designed so as that all events will be available for the end user to assign actions against. I didn't really want to have to duplicate into a manually defined list.
@DotNeter - the available events for each instance of a class - so each instance of `TemperatureSensor` would have the two events `TemperatureOK` and `TemperatureAlarm` listed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you maintain a dictionary keyed by the concrete types of your Capability objects, containing the list of events applicable for each concrete type:

e.g. an instance of `ConcurrentDictionary<Type, EventInfo[]>`

You would populate this just once on startup, calling `Type.GetEvents` on each concrete Capability type used in your system (or if Capability types can be added at runtime via some kind of plugin mechanism, add the events for each plugin type to the dictionary as the plugin is registered).

Thereafter, whenever a Capability is selected from your `List<Capability>`, you can just look up the available events for that device object in the dictionary.

Comment: I hadn't thought of cataloguing them at start up, thank you for the idea.